# zabbix send a very large of false alarms

Tags: zabbix

Hello  I have some simple chech to test port availability:

```
Name: HTTP 1443 - frontend https
Key: net.tcp.service.perf[http,,1443]
```

I create trigger I made two examples of triggers but both are very sensitive and react too quickly

```
Name: Port 1443 is down on {HOST.NAME}
Expression: {Template - INT-ACC:net.tcp.service.perf[http,,1443].last(#3)}=0


Name: Port 1443 is down on {HOST.NAME}
Expression: {Template - INT-ACC:net.tcp.service.perf[http,,1443].count(#3,0,eq)}=0
```

Please give me advice what's wrong, because zabbix send a very large of false alarms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `last` or `count` use `max`, for example `max(#3)}=0`. Then Zabbix will send out an alert after three consecutive failures.